# Scraping html page

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I want to get the movie tittle, year, rating, genres, and run time of five movies from the html page given in the code. These are in the rows of table called results.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def read_from_url(url, num_m=5):
    html_string =  urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
    movie_table = soup.find('table', 'results')  # table of movie
    list_movies = []
    count = 0
    for row in movie_table.find_all("tr"):
        dict_each_movie = {}
        title = title.encode("ascii", "ignore")  # getting title
        dict_each_movie["title"] = title
        year = year.encode("ascii","ignore")     # getting year
        dict_each_movie["year"] = year
        rank = rank.encode("ascii","ignore")     # getting rank
        dict_each_movie["rank"] = rank
        # genres = []  # getting genres of a movie
        runtime = runtime.encode("ascii","ignore")     # getting rank
        dict_each_movie["runtime"] = runtime
        list_movies.append(dict_each_movie)
        count+=1
        if count==num_of_m:
            break
    return list_movies

print read_from_url('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&sort=user_rating&start=1&title_type=feature&year=2005,2015',2)
```

Expected output:

```
[{'rating': '10.0', 'genres': ['Comedy', 'Family'], 'title': 'How to Beat a Bully', 'rank': '1', 'year': '2014', 'runtime': '90'},..........]
```

Comment: What is title in `title = title.encode("ascii", "ignore")`?

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing a variable that hasn't been declared. When the interpreter sees `title.encode("ascii", "ignore")` it looks for the variable `title` which hasn't been declared previously. Python can't possible know what `title` is thus you can't call `encode` on it. Same goes for year and rank. Instead use:

```
title = 'How to Beat a Bully'.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Comment: @ runDosrun, how to automate this?  Should I hard code the title, year, run time etc.?

Comment: My answer addresses your error. In order to achieve your goal you'll have to read more about some basics I'm afraid, see e.g. http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/fetch-movie-details-from-imdb-using-python-with-proxy/

Comment: @runDosun.  I read documentation of beautiful soup and the link you provided in the comment.  The example uses soup.find to get the title. In my case, title is in the results table (for every movie) after inspectng the element of first movie <ahref="/title/tt3981396/">The Forsaken Pages</a>.  Is there any way I get retrieve this title (The Forsaken Pages).

Answer (score 1):

Why so???

Make your life easier with CSS Selectors.

```
<table>
 <tr class="my_class">
  <td id="id_here">

     <a href = "link_here"/>First Link</a>

  </td>
  <td id="id_here">

     <a href = "link_here"/>Second Link</a>

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

    for tr in movie_table.select("tr.my_class"):
            for td in tr.select("td#id_here"):
                print("Link " + td.select("a")[0]["href"])
                print("Text "+ td.select("a")[0].text)
```